# Capturing a particular regular language with $O(m)$ states

Tags: regular-language, nondeterminism

In dx.doi.org/10.1006/inco.2001.3069 the authors defined $NID_m = \{ u\in \{0,1\}^* | \exists i : u_i \neq u_{i + m} \}$ and claimed it could be recognized by a NFA of size $O(m)$.  The paper mentions the NFA simply needs to guess a residue $i$ modulo $m$ and check whether there is a position $p \equiv i\,mod\,m$ with $u_p \neq u_{p + m}$.  I suspect I'm overlooking something simple.  Can anyone point out how this can be done with a linear number of states?

Comment: Maybe better suited for cs.SE as you indeed overlook something simple. Initial state $q_i$ loops with $0,1$. And you have two states connected to state $q_i$, $q_0$ with a $0$ transition, and $q_1$  with a $1$ transition, that is when you "guess" $i$ (you exit state $q_i$). $q_0$ is followed by $m-1$ states connected by a path, all transitions being labeled by $0$ and $1$ but the last, labeled by $0$ only, that is, $u_{i+m}$ has to be $0$ ; last state is accepting and loops until the end of the word. Same trick with $q_1$ but the last transition is labeled by $1$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I understand the claim properly now.